# Why i don't see in the Main Camera preview window anything?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started a new project.

Now it's on normal mode in the Inspector but even if i change it to debug mode there is no any preview property in the camera in the inspector.

I see the preview window of the camera in the scene view but when i move the camera nothing change in the preview window.

[image: New project]

Comment: I found the solution. Changing the Rendering Path from  "use graphics settings" to "legacy deferred". Now it's working fine.

Comment: write this as an answer `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Changing the Rendering Path from "use graphics settings" to "legacy deferred". Now it's working fine.